# How to use official php docker image without interactive mode

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to create a docker image that will spin up a container to run a Minecraft PE server. [PocketMine-MP](https://doc.pmmp.io/en/rtfd/installation/installing-manually.html) a Minecraft PE server.

The server requires PHP binary, and I want to use the official PHP docker image. However, it seems like the php docker image is configured to run in interactive mode.

I just want to use that PHP image since it has the binary in it, and copy over the necessary file to start the server, is there anyway to get rid of the interactive prompt?

I can run the php image in detached mode, but I wasn't sure if there is a better way to approach it.

I hope my intention is clear. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. Seems like running the container in detached and interactive mode with flag -d and -t is the recommended way.